# Need oauth value with js

Tags: javascript, facebook, jsp, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am using JSP and JS for an app on facebook.  I am having trouble finding an answer so I am hoping some one can point me in the right direction.

I have my app installed on multiple fan pages and I want to serve up slightly different content depending on which page its installed on.

I know there has to be a way to retrieve the oauth or some other value that is unique to each fan page but I am not having much luck.

I am also wondering if I am using the wrong terminology

Here is an example of what I was calling the OAUTH value:

http://www.facebook.com/OAUTH?sk=#

sorry I feel like this is a really simple question but I am not finding any answers that seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For a fan page, your app will be send a `signed_request` HTTP POST parameter, which has in it some basic information including which page id is running your app.

See for more information:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/